# How to model multi-blog site?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

I've got these tables:

```
**Sites**
:has_many :blogs
:has_many :pages

**Blogs**
:belongs_to :site

**Pages**
:belongs_to :site
:belongs_to :blog
```

Basically, I want to be able to create Pages that are either related to a Site OR related to a Blog with routes like this:

```
/blogs/1/pages/1
/sites/1/pages/2
```

With my current setup, my Pages table has a foreign_key for blog_id AND site_id - and I was just thinking of doing this:

- if a page is being created for a site (meaning it doesn't belong to a blog) then set blog_id = to NULL, but set site_id accordingly
- but, if a page is being created for a blog (which already belongs to a site) then set the related site_id AND blog_id

Then if I want a list of Site pages:  I can just query the Pages table for all NULL blog_ids, and if I want Blog pages, I'll get them through the relationship with Blog already.

UPDATE:  I accepted the answer below which suggested using "polymorphic associations", but could this also be done using Single Table Inheritance?  If so, which method is better?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use polymorphic associations.

Add a foreign key and a type column to your `pages` table. Find an adjective that describes the common property of the classes that your pages can belong to. I came up with `pageable` (which gives me a `pageable_id` and `pageable_type` column). If you use migrations, add the following your `Page` migration:

```
# Adds "pageable_id" integer column and "pageable_type" string column.
t.references(:pageable, :polymorphic => true)
```

In your models, specify the polymorphic relationship when using `has_many`/`belongs_to`:

```
class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pages, :as => :pageable
end

class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pages, :as => :pageable
end

class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pageable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

And behold:

```
# Return all pages belonging to Site with ID 12, that is, return all pages
# with pageable_id 12 and pageable_type "site".
Site.find(12).pages

# Return all pages belonging to Blog with ID 3, that is, return all pages
# with pageable_id 3 and pageable_type "blog".
Blog.find(3).pages

# Returns the owner (Blog or Site) of Page with ID 27.
Page.find(27).pageable
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into Polymorphic assocations: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Basically, you're on the right track, but there is an existing pattern for what you're trying to do.